# PUDB Error: <no source code available>

Tags: python, pudb

I'm new to pudb.  It run fine for the most-part, but when I try to enter a library it apparently doesn't recognize, I get the following message:

```
  <no source code available>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  If this is generated code and you would like the source code to show up here,
  add it to linecache.cache, like

  import linecache
  linecache.cache[filename] = (size, mtime, lines, fullname)

  You can also set the attribute _MODULE_SOURCE_CODE in the module in which this function
  was compiled to a string containing the code.
```

I've tried importing 'linecache' and the 'cache' attribute is a dictionary.  I've tried creating an entry for the missing module a few times with no success.

Can someone please give an example on an easier and/or practical way to add an unrecognized module to pudb?

Comment: What do you mean by 'unrecognized module'? Could you give an example?

Comment: In my case, it's module (PhidgetsPython/Phidgets/Devices/InterfaceKit.py) located in another directory.  The script has no problem importing the module, but pudb apparently can't see it.   I tried adding that directory to my PYTHONPATH, but it does not appear to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

The way it worked for me is the following.

I got this message when a piece of code was executed that has been generated on-the-fly. I tracked down the location where the code was generated, and added:

```
import linecache
linecache.cache[__file__] = (len(source), 0, source, __file__)
```

(where the `source` variable corresponds to the generated source)

What I observed after, was that in `pudb` interactive mode, in the stack list a new item appeared. This new item was preceeding the one that throws the `<no source code available>` message.

When I navigate on this new item, I can see the generated source.

Comment: What about code that is **not** generated?  I'm getting this for the first time after using pudb for several years without incident.  None of the code is generated.

Anything special I need to know about Python3?  First time debugging Py3 script.

Interesting note:  I normally use set_trace() strategically located, rather than entering the debugger using "python3 -m pudb ..."  However, when I do that, it hits the set_trace() breakpoint and there is no source.  If, instead, I enter the debugger using '-m pudb' and then hit continue, which then stops at the set_trace(), the source appears.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/513#issuecomment-609035539). A possible workaround is to use the full path of the script.

Quite simply, instead of `python script.py`, use `python /full/path/to/script.py`.

This works because some libraries may use `chdir` to change directories and when that happens, `pudb` cannot locate the script, resulting in the error.

**TIP**: To save some keystrokes, you can simply type `python $PWD/script.py` instead of typing in the full path.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and in my case it was because the package was being installed as .egg, you can circumvent that installing with `pip install -e foo_package`